# Close list of Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, html

I have this dropdown menu:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  allNameMuseums().forEach(function(item) { // ITERAZIONE
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").innerHTML += '<a onclick="updateData(this)">' + item + '</a>';
  })
});

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Museo1</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want that when I click an item in the list of dropdown menu, the list closes automatically.

Comment: You are adding anchor elements into a div element. so... I guess remove those anchors once you select an option? It's not clear how your "dropdown" works.

Comment: It works in this way: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_filter but I have no links @daddygames

Comment: `<a onclick="updateData(this)">` is a link. Since you've not included all of the necessary code to reproduce, you will get guesses, like [the existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52628416) which likely won't help. Please include everything necessary to reproduce your problem, **in the question itself**, not on an external site. See [mcve] for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you need is remove the "show" class from the element.

---

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn { background-color: #4CAF50; color: white; padding: 16px; font-size: 16px; border: none; cursor: pointer; }
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus { background-color: #3e8e41; }
#myInput { border-box: box-sizing; background-image: url('searchicon.png'); background-position: 14px 12px; background-repeat: no-repeat; font-size: 16px; padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px; border: none; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; }
#myInput:focus { outline: 3px solid #ddd; }
.dropdown { position: relative; display: inline-block; }
.dropdown-content { display: none; position: absolute; background-color: #f6f6f6; min-width: 230px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid #ddd; z-index: 1; }
.dropdown-content a { color: black; padding: 12px 16px; text-decoration: none; display: block; }
.dropdown a:hover { background-color: #ddd; }
.show { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Search/Filter Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu [...]</p>

<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#about" onclick="select()">Item1</a>
    <a href="#base" onclick="select()">Item2</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

function select() {
  //Your item selection logic here...
  myFunction();
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Renato Lucas Chitolina With false, I cannot open anymore dropdown menu

Comment: @Mario I've added an example snippet. I hope it helps.

Comment: You don't have to use a different function. Just call myfunction from the anchor click and it will work. I've tested this. You also do not need the boolean parameter if you do it this way.

Comment: Answer updated according to the @daddygames suggestion

Comment: @Mario watch out in _myFunction()_, that now is called both inside button to show dropdown items and inside anchors to hide dropdown items.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the example in W3C School [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp):

What you are missing is, closing the dropdown when the click is outside the button:

```
// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try yourself](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown)

And notice, this example doesn't have your search bar, so in this function, you'll have to check with the search bar as well to exclude it from closing the drop down.